# Angular Material md-subheader not sticky

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using several `<md-subheader>`s on my page, but they are not sticking to the top when the user scrolls down (like in the [demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/subheader)).

Any ideas? Maybe my layout is causing the problem?

```
<body>
  <div>
    <md-toolbar>
    <div>
      <md-sidenav>
      <md-content>
        <section>
          <md-subheader>
...
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/lebolo/pen/KzmZbB).

---

Based on another [question I had](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36193493/1370556), just adding `layout="column" layout-fill` to the top `div` works, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `section`s fit inside `md-content`. So, when you scroll, you don't scroll inside `md-content`. In order for the stickiness to work, you should scroll inside of `md-content`.

I gave a height of 500px to `md-content` so that you can see the effect.

```
<md-content layout="column" layout-padding flex style="height: 500px;">

    <!-- Report content -->

    <section ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
```

Here is the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/turgutsaricam/pen/LNLPJW?editors=1000).

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a solution, but I don't want to restrict the height of my `md-content`. Is there any way to get them to stick in my scenario? Or is that just not how sticky `md-subheader` should be used?

Comment: Based on another [question I had](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36193493/1370556), just adding `layout="column" layout-fill` to the top div works.