# md-content Scroll Issue in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, scrollbar

I designed a web page with header, content body and footer using Responsive and Angular Material. The Content Body has the `md-content`, inside it has multiple `<p>` paragraph text content. I set the overflow to auto (`overflow: auto`). But I can't able to scroll the content.

The following Source Code Contains HTML, AngularJS and CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
<style>

html, body {height: 100%; margin:0px !important;}

header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #777;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-color:#ffffcc;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}

footer{
    background-color: #777;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.contentdemoBasicUsage div.demo-content {
  height: 600px; }

.contentdemoBasicUsage div[ng-controller] {
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 15px; }

.contentdemoBasicUsage md-content {
  padding: 24px; 
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  overflow:auto;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<header class="header">my header</header>
    <div class="content">
<div ng-app="MyApp" class="contentdemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="">
  <md-toolbar class="md-warn">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h2 class="md-flex">Toolbar: md-warn</h2>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
 
  <md-content flex="" layout-padding="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei. Sea omnium invenire mediocrem at, in lobortis conclusionemque nam. Ne deleniti appetere reprimique pro, inani labitur disputationi te sed. At vix sale omnesque, id pro labitur reformidans accommodare, cum labores honestatis eu. Nec quem lucilius in, eam praesent reformidans no. Sed laudem aliquam ne.</p>

    <p>
Facete delenit argumentum cum at. Pro rebum nostrum contentiones ad. Mel exerci tritani maiorum at, mea te audire phaedrum, mel et nibh aliquam. Malis causae equidem vel eu. Noster melius vis ea, duis alterum oporteat ea sea. Per cu vide munere fierent.
    </p>

    <p>
Ad sea dolor accusata consequuntur. Sit facete convenire reprehendunt et. Usu cu nonumy dissentiet, mei choro omnes fuisset ad. Te qui docendi accusam efficiantur, doming noster prodesset eam ei. In vel posse movet, ut convenire referrentur eum, ceteros singulis intellegam eu sit.
    </p>

    <p>
Sit saepe quaestio reprimique id, duo no congue nominati, cum id nobis facilisi. No est laoreet dissentias, idque consectetuer eam id. Clita possim assueverit cu his, solum virtute recteque et cum. Vel cu luptatum signiferumque, mel eu brute nostro senserit. Blandit euripidis consequat ex mei, atqui torquatos id cum, meliore luptatum ut usu. Cu zril perpetua gubergren pri. Accusamus rationibus instructior ei pro, eu nullam principes qui, reque justo omnes et quo.
    </p>

    <p>
Sint unum eam id. At sit fastidii theophrastus, mutat senserit repudiare et has. Atqui appareat repudiare ad nam, et ius alii incorrupte. Alii nullam libris his ei, meis aeterno at eum. Ne aeque tincidunt duo. In audire malorum mel, tamquam efficiantur has te.
    </p>

    <p>
Qui utamur tacimates quaestio ad, quod graece omnium ius ut. Pri ut vero debitis interpretaris, qui cu mentitum adipiscing disputationi. Voluptatum mediocritatem quo ut. Fabulas dolorem ei has, quem molestie persequeris et sit.
    </p>

    <p>
Est in vivendum comprehensam conclusionemque, alia cetero iriure no usu, te cibo deterruisset pro. Ludus epicurei quo id, ex cum iudicabit intellegebat. Ex modo deseruisse quo, mel noster menandri sententiae ea, duo et tritani malorum recteque. Nullam suscipit partiendo nec id, indoctum vulputate per ex. Et has enim habemus tibique. Cu latine electram cum, ridens propriae intellegat eu mea.
    </p>

    <p>
Duo at aliquid mnesarchum, nec ne impetus hendrerit. Ius id aeterno debitis atomorum, et sed feugait voluptua, brute tibique no vix. Eos modo esse ex, ei omittam imperdiet pro. Vel assum albucius incorrupte no. Vim viris prompta repudiare ne, vel ut viderer scripserit, dicant appetere argumentum mel ea. Eripuit feugait tincidunt pri ne, cu facilisi molestiae usu.
    </p>

    <p>
Qui utamur tacimates quaestio ad, quod graece omnium ius ut. Pri ut vero debitis interpretaris, qui cu mentitum adipiscing disputationi. Voluptatum mediocritatem quo ut. Fabulas dolorem ei has, quem molestie persequeris et sit.
    </p>

    <p>
Est in vivendum comprehensam conclusionemque, alia cetero iriure no usu, te cibo deterruisset pro. Ludus epicurei quo id, ex cum iudicabit intellegebat. Ex modo deseruisse quo, mel noster menandri sententiae ea, duo et tritani malorum recteque. Nullam suscipit partiendo nec id, indoctum vulputate per ex. Et has enim habemus tibique. Cu latine electram cum, ridens propriae intellegat eu mea.
    </p>

    <p>
Duo at aliquid mnesarchum, nec ne impetus hendrerit. Ius id aeterno debitis atomorum, et sed feugait voluptua, brute tibique no vix. Eos modo esse ex, ei omittam imperdiet pro. Vel assum albucius incorrupte no. Vim viris prompta repudiare ne, vel ut viderer scripserit, dicant appetere argumentum mel ea. Eripuit feugait tincidunt pri ne, cu facilisi molestiae usu.
    </p>
  </md-content>

</div>
</div>
    <footer class="footer">my footer</footer>
<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. 
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be in foundin the LICENSE file at http://material.angularjs.org/license.
-->
<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188444/angular-material-md-toolbar-not-sticking-md-scroll-shrink/36193493#36193493

Comment: @sdfacre I tried it But it won't work... Kindly check it once please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add layout-fill to your ng-app div

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" class="contentdemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" layout-fill>
....
```

see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwONQV

Comment: Thanks. <md-content><md-content></md-content><md-content></md-content></md-content> How to make float: left for the inner md-content. Kindly assist me...

Comment: add layout='row' to the outer md-content. check https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction for angular material layout

Comment: How to make mobile responsive? md-content has 2 inner md-content. In Mobile View the 2 inner md-content should be placed top and bottom not like left and reight. Kindly assist me...

Comment: add layout-xs="column"to the outer md-content. so your outer md-content should have both layout="row" and layout-xs="column".

Comment: Thanks. one more help. How to remove height property for mobile devices. Because right-now height is set to device viewport height. If it is a mobile. I need to remove the height. Kindly assist me...

Comment: does that mean you want to scroll on the whole page rather than on md-content on mobile?

Comment: In my Question Post. I set the Content in between header and footer. So, the height of the page is restricted to device viewport height. So, i need to relax the height only for mobile devices.

Comment: just google @media and use it to apply the height setting on specific width.

Answer (score 0):

Property Value for overflow-

- visible - The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box. This is default
- hidden - The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible
- scroll - The overflow is clipped, but a scroll-bar is added to see the rest of the content
- auto -   If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content
- initial -    Sets this property to its default value. Read about initial
- inherit -    Inherits this property from its parent element. Read about inherit

Try to use  **scroll** value for overflow.